# Chrome Extension No-Refresh

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am looking to have my chrome extension running even when the popup is not shown. I have a basic popup.html file that displays the extension. Then I have several javascript files that need to be running constantly. The extension is essentially a timer that keeps track of how long it has been running until you stop it. The problem is that it works until you close the extension to do something else in chrome. I am looking to have it continue to count time even when the popup is not being shown.

**My manifest.json includes: "persistent": true;

Do I need to have my scripts in the background.js file?

Comment: You could just save the timer start timestamp to storage and read it and display the counter when you open the popup again.

Comment: The background scripts run in a separate hidden background page, which is not related to the popup page, so you probably need to rework your extension because the popup scripts run only when the popup is shown.